# Converting yyyy-mm-dd date format into yyyymmdd in R

Tags: r, date, format

I see there are many solutions for converting yyyymmdd to yyyy-mm-dd format, but it is hard to find a code that converts yyyy-mm-dd to yyyymmdd.

What would be the best way to convert a date format yyyy-mm-dd to yyyymmdd?

Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
format(as.Date("1970-01-01"), "%Y%m%d")
```